# Android Studio "waiting for debugger"

Tags: android, android-studio

I've created simple "Hello, world!" project using android studio.
When I run it on the device or emulator - everything is fine.
Then I make attempt to run it in the debug mode - and it fails after a few minutes "waiting for debugger" dialog on the screen and

```
`Error running test-test: Unable to open debugger port : java.io.IOException`
```

message in event log.

How can I solve this problem?

Michael Yunusov this problem was on different machines the same time.

**Solution:** I had two IDEs running the same time: Android studio and 
 Eclipse. Closing one of them fixed the issue.

Comment: ever rebooted your machine?

Comment: Problem was in conflict between ide's (Eclipse and AS). I had to close one of them)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debugging with Android Studio stuck at "Waiting For Debugger" forever](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436050/debugging-with-android-studio-stuck-at-waiting-for-debugger-forever)

Answer (score 3):

Try to reset your ADB.

To reset the ADB server:
Open Run-> Cmd-> adb kill-server

To start it again you can use:
Open Run-> Cmd-> adb devices

Comment: At least in OSX you need to start the adb service with `adb start-server` before running `adb devices`

Comment: It doesn't work for me... The "Waiting for Debugger" message is still there when I run the app.

Comment: I can't find anything like a "Cmd" item in my "Run" menu on my Android Studio.

Comment: @hippietrail You can open a terminal window through your OS and run "adb kill-server" and "adb start-server".

Answer (score 1):

**How it worked for me.**

**1.** Start Android Device Monitor from **Tools** -> **Android** -> **Android Device Monitor**

**2.** Click on **Stop** for the process you are facing the issue from list of devices.

Comment: If you can post your same answer to multiple questions, the questions are probably duplicate. Flag them as such instead of copying your answer around the site.

Comment: I don't even have a Tools/Android menu in my Android Studio and Help/Find Action did not find anything similar to Android Device Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

When i had this problem it was as a result of an invalid android manifest

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Setting* > *Developer Options* > open *Revoke USB debugging authorizations* >choose *OK*

If you cannot find Developer Options: go to [Settings] > [About Phone], and tap [Version] for 7 times