# How to automatically uninstall android app from device before installing a new version

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Android studio with Gradle builds. I test my app on a device and let Android Studio and Gradle build the app and install it on the device. How can I tell Gradle or Android Studio to uninstall the app from the device before installing a new version?

Comment: Why don' you try running your app and see if it removes the existing app, then installs a new one, or else?

Comment: It does not remove the existing app, I think. Since the user data for the app still exists after the second install.

Comment: @Biu: the default behavior is to simply install the apk, which results in an update.

Comment: apparently the command line `gradle uninstallDebug` should uninstall the app

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Apparently, if you in `Run -> Edit Configurations...`, on the left side there is a expendable list of Android configurations.

Select yours, on the right side of the window are details on the configuration, at the bottom of that section is the `Before launch` section.

Create a `gradle-aware Make`, given the task `:app:uninstallAll` or `:app:uninstallDebug` whichever suits you. (There is autocompletion to get all the available tasks, `app` may vary if you have several modules).

Comment: How can i do that embedded in the apk? meaning that before installing a new apk it will uninstall old one?

Comment: @dowi Why do You want to do so in the APK ?

Comment: @code2be because i use retrofit which does not have a migration process. the db itself is synced with a server so i had no problem to lose it, install the new apk with new db scheme and download the data. since then i found that i can version the scheme and when it sees a new scheme it empties the db automatically and then i sync from server

Comment: why would retrofit have anything to do with a migration process?

Comment: @njzk2 do you know if there is a way to call the task only when a certain build variant is selected? I'd like to uninstall my `release` build but only when I'm about to run it

Comment: Fails if the app doesn't installed

Comment: `:app:uninstallAll` gives error Project 'app' not found in root project 'xxxx'.

Comment: @dowi if you found solution, please help [here]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704991/automatically-uninstall-older-app-before-installing-new-android-app

Comment: meant GreenDAO, not Retrofit :-\

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to uninstall the current build variant. The above solution needs the name ("uninstallDEBUG")

Answer (score 12):

The current answer is a little outdated, these are the simplest steps:

- Select <kbd>Edit Configurations</kbd> from the dropwdown
- Find the section <kbd>Before Launch: Gradle task, Gradle-aware Make</kbd>
- Click <kbd>+</kbd> and choose <kbd>Run Gradle task</kbd>
- In the <kbd>Gradle project</kbd> field, select the root of your project
- In the <kbd>Tasks</kbd> field enter `:app:uninstallAll` or equivalent
- Leave the other fields blank and press <kbd>OK</kbd>
- Reorder the tasks so your new one is first / top of the list

Comment: this worked for me with A.S. 2020.3.1 (artic fox).

Answer (score 0):

**React Native Developers**

just replace the android script in your package.json

replace this script

```
    "android": "react-native run-android",
```

with this script

```
    "android": "cd android && ./gradlew :app:uninstallAll && react-native run-android",
```

the new script will uninstall the previous apk from the connected device before installing the new one
just hit yarn android or npm android(your preference)