# How do I uninstall and re-run an app on a device using Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I am new to Android Studio and I feel that I must be doing something wrong. When running MyApp on an actual device the process goes like this.

- Edit code.
- Select the `Run` command in Android Studio. (Shift+F10)
- Discover a Bug (on phone)
- Navigate to Settings --> Application --> MyApp (on phone)
- Force Stop (on phone)
- Uninstall MyApp (on phone)
- Edit code
- Select the 'Run' command in Android Studio.
- Repeat again and again.

This is repetitive and time consuming. Is there a way to uninstall MyApp via Android Studio?

If not is there some other more automated way to do this?

BTW I have seen this question [How to automatically uninstall android app from device before installing a new version](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28076751/1783439) but it does not sufficiently address the issue.

Comment: 1. fix the bug 2. Shift+F10 is enough(it should update the app) ... why you are uninstalling the app ?

Comment: If you need to specifically test what the app is doing on first install, here's a hack you can do: set the version code to a high number, and then decrease it by one each time you run the app.  Android Studio will detect that the device already has a newer version and offer to uninstall it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically uninstall android app from device before installing a new version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076751/how-to-automatically-uninstall-android-app-from-device-before-installing-a-new-v)

Comment: @umitems That question does not result in the answer I was looking for nor is that question as specific as this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the force stop and uninstall step by just hitting `run` again. Android Studio should prompt you which device to run on and there you can select your connected device.

It will close the app and re-run your changed version.

Answer (score 94):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076751/how-to-automatically-uninstall-android-app-from-device-before-installing-a-new-v/28077408#28077408) is what you're looking for. Basically edit your configuration to perform an uninstall before app launch.

From the Run menu -> Edit Configurations... -> Before Launch -> Add Gradle-aware Make -> ":app:uninstallAll"

[image]

Comment: This answer helped me more than the accepted one. Later versions of AS have an issue with not being able to detect whether you've uninstalled an APK and will try to install "restart patches" instead, but they fail if the APK was uninstalled due to clearing databases, clean installs, etc.

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for

Comment: You really helped me. My cellphone got a dark screen because of my app, so I needed to uninstall the app, but with my cellphone in dark the only solution was uninstall that app from Android Studio. I did not think it was even possible, but it worked. Thank you ! My cellphone is OK now. However, I need to know why this happen.
Thanks !

Comment: This is not the right answer to the question. BUT, due to the tittle of the question (that is wrong too), all people that are ending on this page are looking for this information (instead of the right answer).

Answer (score 10):

You can execute the gradle task `:app:uninstallAll` to uninstall the app. The next time you hit `Run` your app will be reinstalled.

[image: Android Studio Gradle Tab with selected uninstallAll task]

Answer (score 4):

You can make just like this now. Check mark on `Clear app storage before deployment`.

[image]

[image]

**UPD**: Unfortunately it need to make for all new projects each time. But solution works super good.

Answer (score 2):

I always just hit the "debug" icon (the bug icon) and from the debug tab (at the bottom of your screen), you can stop running the app by clicking on the stop button.  No need to uninstall/reinstall app.  When you're done, you can do a release build of the apk.