# Android Studio 2.1.2 and Android 6: Error while installing restart patches

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-studio-2.1

Since updating to Android 6, I get

"Error installing cold swap patches: com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunPushFailedException: Error creating folder with: run-as swiss.seabird.seabirdapp1 mkdir -p /data/data/swiss.seabird.seabirdapp1/files/instant-run/dex
Error while Installing restart patches"

every time I try to run my app, unless it was previously uninstalled or I do a completely new build.

I tried: a) setting write permissions for the app on my mobile device  b) updating the SDK with all tools etc for APK 23. c) unklicking "Restart activity on code changes" in Android Settings, as recommended in another thread on stackoverflow d) specifically selecting this app for debugging in developer settings on my mobile device. None of this worked.

I'm running Android Studio 2.1.2 on Windows 10, and installing the app on a Samsung S5. Previously, with Android 5.1, this problem didn't exist.

Would appreciate any help - thanks in advance!

Comment: Not very helpful but have you considered turning off Instant run http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35168753/instant-run-in-android-studio-2-0-how-to-turn-off

Comment: Here a possible solution: [Solution with Android 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41593364/7405249)

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem and i got to know that this problem is created because it helps the gradle

Answer (score 0):

I found that this solution works for me, using AndroidStudio 2.1.3 and Android 6.0.1: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41595313/7405249

I think that from AndroidStudio 2.1.1 to 2.1.3 the solution could works too.