# android instant run alway fail

Tags: android, gradle

`Error installing cold swap patches: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
Error while Installing restart patches`

I have tried everything I can, but no luck.

([Error while Installing restart patches when launching android app with Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36680036/error-while-installing-restart-patches-when-launching-android-app-with-android-s))

anyone can help me out?

gradle: 3.2.1
android studio: 2.2.3

Log:

```
2017-01-06 20:56:00,710 [9781722]   WARN -                    #InstantRun - Failed to push dex files:  
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
  at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
  at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
  at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.ApplicationPatchUtil.write(ApplicationPatchUtil.java:53)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.ApplicationPatchUtil.write(ApplicationPatchUtil.java:42)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunClient$4.communicate(InstantRunClient.java:399)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunClient$4.communicate(InstantRunClient.java:393)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunClient.talkToAppWithinPortForward(InstantRunClient.java:233)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunClient.talkToApp(InstantRunClient.java:202)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunClient.pushPatches(InstantRunClient.java:393)
  at com.android.tools.fd.client.InstantRunClient.pushPatches(InstantRunClient.java:349)
  at com.android.tools.idea.fd.InstantRunManager.pushArtifacts(InstantRunManager.java:187)
  at com.android.tools.idea.run.tasks.DexDeployTask.perform(DexDeployTask.java:56)
  at com.android.tools.idea.run.LaunchTaskRunner.run(LaunchTaskRunner.java:114)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
  at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
  at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please do following steps

```
I think the problem is due to instant run feature of Android Studio 2.0.and above This might help

1.Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
2.Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes
```

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart hope this helps:)

Comment: change the gradle version  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3' in project level build gradle hope this helps ;)

Comment: It's already 2.2.3..... But I solve this issue. I try to use my colleague's android device, and find instant run can work with his device, and then I switch back to my device, it can work now, I don't know why, but it really works now. TNX for your help.

Comment: It works with my colleague's device which is android 6.0. Mine is android 5.0. I am not sure if it is related

Comment: multidexenabled true in your build gradle

Comment: add this line to build gradle dexOptions{
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

Comment: now, I am using,  ` javaMaxHeapSize "3g"`  multidexenabled already there

Comment: try change the application class of manifest to android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" hope this help

Comment: this? 
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132512/discussion-between-leon-and-pratik-mohanrao-gondil).