# Android clean build gradle task

Tags: android, gradle

Is this an existing gradle android task that uninstall the current app, rebuild, install and run it in one go, or do I need to define a custom task for this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, off course. Whenever you initiate the execution, it is build & installed. For the second time, it executes the changes that are made, re-builds & installed. All of the them are carried away, by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it easily.

> Apparently, if you in Run -> Edit Configurations..., on the left side
>   there is a expendable list of Android configurations.
>
> Select yours, on the right side of the window are details on the
>   configuration, at the bottom of that section is the Before launch
>   section.
>
> Create a gradle-aware Make, given the task :app:uninstallAll or
>   :app:uninstallDebug whichever suits you. (There is autocompletion to
>   get all the available tasks, app may vary if you have several
>   modules).

Read this articles:

[How to automatically uninstall android app from device before installing a new version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076751/how-to-automatically-uninstall-android-app-from-device-before-installing-a-new-v)

[Android Studio : How to uninstall APK (or execute adb command) automatically before Run or Debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927124/how-to-uninstall-apk-or-execute-adb-command-automatically-before-run-or-debug)