# Automatically uninstalling the older app before installing the new one

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, google-play-console

I published my app on play store and I have made an update that may cause the older one to crash due to some database structure changes that I have made and I have had a hell of hustle trying to automate DB migration upon installation. So I want the to completely auto-uninstall the old one from users phone before new one is installed during update as an easy solution. Is there a way I can include such configurations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to force uninstallation before installation. But it sounds like you could just delete your DB on upgrade using [SQLiteOpenHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper)

Answer (score -1):

If you use GreenDAO
you can use the schema version
Schema schema = new Schema(, "greendao");

when increasing the schema version GreenDAO will empty your DB and update the schema, and then you can repopulate it from the server (if applicable)

Comment: Thanks for your response, though something is not clear to me. I use Room Database and I have adopted Singleton approach in Database access, therefore I don't see anywhere/how I can use the schema instance created using `Schema schema = new Schema(, "greendao");` since I also don't understand what you mean by `"greendao" ` in terms of whether it's `tablename` or `database name` since `DAO`s are not explicitly named.

Comment: GreenDAO is an ORM for Android:
http://greenrobot.org/greendao/
I am not familiar with Room DB