# A debugger is already attached. Need to restart Android Studio to fix

Tags: android-studio, debugging, adb

I am on a mac running 10.13.5 and Android Studio 3.2.1. Gradle is gradle-4.6-all.zip.

This started after updating Android Studio to 3.2.1.

It seems that whenever app crashes or if device  goes to sleep(testing on real device) when I try to rerun the app I get either the 'A debugger is already attached' or a series of lines of

```
Waiting for application to come online: ...
```

followed by:

```
Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session.
```

Clicking on the red 'Stop' icon before attempting to rerun the app with debugger doesn't help.

I have used adb kill-server, adb start-server with no luck.

I have tried restarting app on device and then clicking on the 'Attach debugger to Android Process' icon but I get:

```
 Error running 'Android Debugger (8600)': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8600): java.net.SocketException "Connection reset"
```

The only way to get back to being able to rerun the app in debug mode is to exit and then restart Android Studio.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does connecting new device which you have not previously connected in your android studio works fine?

Comment: Follow these steps if it works fine 1.Android-Studio : File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart 2.Revoke USB debugging authorizations in developer options in your mobile

Comment: I thought I tried that at one point with no luck - sorry I didn't put that in above. But for now I resolved my problem. I went back to AS 3.1.4 and it seems  to be behaving much better.  (I did try 3.2.0 but had same problem.)

Comment: Here is an stackoverflow post that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723813/not-able-to-debug-app-on-android-device-android-studio-2-0

Comment: Back to square one I guess. My downgrade to 3.1.4 worked ok yesterday. Today back to same problem. My quest continues.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this case?

Comment: AS is utter trash some times