# How to fix the error which is "Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session"

Tags: android-studio

when I am going to debug my application using android studio, I cannot do that because of this massage which is `Waiting for application to come online: com.example.myapplication | com.example.myapplication.test` . After sometime `Could not connect to remote process. Aborting debug session` is shown.

Comment: The device might have gone offline. Restart the device and try again

Comment: I tried but It didn't work, please help

Comment: Go in the file menu and click on **Invalidate cache and restart**. It should work after the restart

Comment: It also didn't work

Comment: Your question is duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723813/not-able-to-debug-app-on-android-device-android-studio-2-0. Visit the link to check out plethora of answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not able to debug app on android device - Android Studio 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723813/not-able-to-debug-app-on-android-device-android-studio-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This work for me:

in directory C:\Users\your_name\ .android\avd I deleted all devices and then in Android Studio i created them again.

Before this, I tried **Invalidate cache and restart** option, some restarts/reboots of Android Studio/Devices/PC and deleting devices in Android Virtual Device Manager all of them with no results.

Comment: "Invalidate cache and restart" worked for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but I had the same issue and could not get it to work, I then found in my app config that the Launch option was on nothing, changing that to "Default activity" fixed it for me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me:

- Go to Tools-> AVD Manager
- Delete your Virtual device:
  [image]
- Create a new Virtual device

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The app didn't launch when I tried to run it without debugging. Debugging gave the same results as for OP. No real info about the issue.

The solution was looking through the recent changes I made.
My mistake was that I declared a permission under the `<application>` tag in the manifest file:

```
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET"
```

instead of writing

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

above the `<application>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was in IntelliJ Idea being open along with Android Studio at the same time.
Closing IntelliJ Idea fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Android Studio and my phone worked for me