# My Android device doesn't show on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, usb

I want to debug my Android app with my tablet(Samsung). I enabled usb debugging in Developer Options. When I connect my tablet to my PC, I click 'Allow' for enabling access to the device. But the device doesn't show on Android Studio. I click 'Troubleshoot Device Connections' and it says 'Device is waiting for you to grant permission.' under 'Found 1 device with possible problems. Also, under that there are 12 devices under 'Found 12 devices not recognized as Android devices' and my device also is shown there.

I tried to install Samsung Usb Driver via Device Manager and it says MTP drive is already installed. May this MTP drives be problem when connecting device to Android Studio? If so, how can I delete this MTP driver and install Samsung USB driver?

Comment: 1. Make sure that `ADB is installed 2. Kill the ADB server and start it again 3. Check the answers cases here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723813/not-able-to-debug-app-on-android-device-android-studio-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the settings `install via usb` is enabled too.