# I can't run my new Android app in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am a beginner in Android studio and programming Android. I know Pascal and Python.

I have a [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) page that I wanted to make a app for my site to open it from the Android and have some options in the app like *Contact us*, *About us*, etc.. and when I tried to debug or run the app I got this error message:

> Waiting For Debugger. Application TecharenaGR (process com.example.techarena.techarenagr) is waiting for the debugger to
> attach.

I also tried to reboot my device ([Samsung Galaxy S8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_S8)), reboot my pc. The dev options on the smartphone are open.

The guide I followed to make that simple app was *"[How to Convert a Website into Android Application using Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5dlmqM9Oo8&t=80s)"*.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The debugger is waiting for the app to launch, just open the app on phone, it'll connect and starts debugging.

Comment: if i open the app says TecharenaGR has stopped.

Comment: Post the stacktrace

Comment: i cant find this option stacktrace, is debug , logcat? and how to export it? thankssss

Comment: Yes, Logcat, post the error logs

Comment: its to loong i cant lol

Comment: here is the logcat i upload it on mega.nz           https://mega.nz/#!6tMQEKLA!ukL-tIYvQOT99l_9Wc2rY7wIyAGhlIcQafb-3ryDV54

Comment: just started a new project and fix the problem with the app. so another question i have

how i can put a button on the right side that can have 3 lines in a row and open like settings, and a option that will say contact with us? Also i want a button pull refresh that is red colour i think. so the other can pull down the page and refresh it. can someone help me?

my app link

https://mega.nz/#!e8EUwAYR!L2G-ePC_lCJU1M2r9trYbxL9AkHScE7h8cyx6Wr-rfE

Comment: there is no option to add settings button while i have select the basic i think project on first step on android studio?

Comment: go to the developer option try for install via usb option hope this help

Comment: refer this

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27436050/debugging-with-android-studio-stuck-at-waiting-for-debugger-forever