# how to test an app without a USB cable which attaches the device to the debugger?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android studio and have just made a new app, which uses position sensors.

All is well when the device is usb connected to the debugger. When I unplug the cable, the app runs fine and I can wave the device around, going to a different room etc. .

But when the app is restarted without that cable, it is "waiting for debugger", which is a little annoying at that point.

I have seen this https://developer.android.com/studio/run#changing-variant but that way I need to sign the app, and I fail on that.

Is there a way to run the app without signing it, and without that debugger cable?

To be more precise in view of the two answers that suggested wi-fi connections (which I can't verify at the moment because the box running AS doesn't have wf-fi connection).

I want to test the app even without debugging, and test it by changing location, too. So I would have to set up a wi-fi connection that would connect to AS over really long distances.

Instead I just want to tell the app (or the device): *forget about the debugger.*

This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56541740/4142984 solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

For the first time you must need to connect device to the android adb and after that you can remove it and still get connection to the android adb.

you should install Android Wifi ADB

[image: Install Android Wifi ADB plugin from market place]

you need to connect first time your device with cable in usb debug mode and by using this plugin you can connect your device on the wifi after that you can remove the cable from the system and you will get connected your device to the Android Studio

Note : make sure your system and mobile device must be connected with the same wifi network.

Comment: Thank you, this ould be a n option in other situations. But I don't have wi-fi on the box.

Answer (score 0):

1.Download android-sdk-platform-tools
2. Add the path to environment variables
3. Connect your phone to usb cable
4. Connect your phone and computer in same network(WiFi)\

Now in cmd
5.`adb tcpip 5555`
6. `adb connect *your_phone_ip*:5555` 

Now you can unplug the usb cable.

Comment: Thank yo for your answer. I have already successfully connected the debugger to my device via usb. Does that mean android-sdk-platform-tools are already installed? Second, I cannot connect to my box via wi-fi, as it has no wi-fi-dongle. Maybe your answer is a solutuin but I would need new hardware first.